# Generar diccionario con value variable en C#, cada llamada puede ser una clase diferente de entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, diccionarios

estoy tratando de crear una función que me devuelva un diccionario, en el que usaré la key como indice para buscar muy rápido y los values van a ser un registro completo de la base de datos (usando entity framework).

El problema es que cada vez que llame a la función, la "Tabla" va a ser diferente, con lo cual no se como acceder en entity framework a esa tabla concreta ni tampoco se como acceder al campo para obtener el valor de cada registro, porque solo tengo el nombre del campo en "NombreIndice", pero es una string. Quizá esto ultimo se pueda hacer con reflexión, pero tampoco se como hace.

¿Alguien que sepa de este tema?

Gracias!

```
public static Dictionary<string, ARTICULOS> LeerDiccionarioTablaIndex<T>(T Tabla, string NombreIndice)
    {
        Dictionary<string, ARTICULOS> ret =new Dictionary<string, ARTICULOS>();

        using(DBEntity db = new DBEntity())
        {
            List<ARTICULOS> lista = (from a in db.ARTICULOS select a).ToList();

            foreach(ARTICULOS a in lista)
            {
                PropertyInfo[] properties = Tabla.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                {
                    if (property.Name == NombreIndice)
                    {
                        ret.Add(a.CODARTICULO.ToString(), a);
                    }
                }
            }             
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: No entiendo porque si consulta siempre a la tabla Articulos, para que queres pasarle otro T diferente y con reflection que queres logar? en tu "lista" tenes todo para recorrer y asignarle a tu Diccionario los valores que quieres.

Comment: Hola Ramiro, la función la quiero crear porque me gustaria que sirviera para hacerlo con cualquier tabla, simplemente pasandole la clase "TABLA" de entity framework y el string con el "INDICE" tal y como se llama en la base de datos. En el ejemplo serian: "ARTICULO" como clase (se llama la tabla así) y "CODARTICULO" como string porque es key unica en esa tabla